# Create svn branch from url of working copy

Tags: svn, branch

Using SVN command-line, how can I create a branch from the URL of my current working copy? (NOT from my local working copy, which may have local changes)

Looking for a direct way, without going through "svn info" to get the URL.

Comment: is using svn info in a shell script ok for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

`svn copy ^/@HEAD <Branch URL>`

**EDIT**

As branches, tags, and the trunk are just paths and completely arbitrary in SVN, I don't think you'll be able to accomplish what you're trying to do without getting a little creative (e.g. outside of a built-in SVN command). To accomplish what I think you want to do, you can use a bash script (assuming Mac/Linux):

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_URL=$(svn info | grep ^URL | cut -d" " -f2)

svn copy $CURRENT_URL "^/branches/$1"
```

Usage: `svnbranch.sh newbranch`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question - looking to copy from the URL of the current working copy. Also ^@HEAD doesn't work, needs to be ^/@HEAD.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood that part of your request. So, you want to be able to branch + switch from current trunk OR a current branch (whatever it the current working directory of your local working directory) without specifying any URL?

Comment: Yes. Just a branch (without switch) is also ok.

Comment: Scripting seems to be the possible way.

Answer (score 1):

You can just perform

```
svn copy <URL of existing URI> <New URL>
```

You can obtain the URL of the existing working copy thanks to "svn info".

The  should not exist in the SVN server tree, or you'll in fact create a subdirectory in that URL.

The copy will occur directly on the server. You will in fact directly "Commit" your change, without needing any working copy.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any more direct way though?

Comment: You are welcome. More direct would been "svn add <URL of branch>" ?

Comment: I meant without getting the URL first. Similar to using the caret notation (but the caret is no good since it points to the root of the repo).

Comment: @Danra: Sorry but what do you mean by caret notation ?

Answer (score 1):

Run `svn help copy' and carefully read its output. I think --revision option might help.